# flutter save model as json in local storage

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to make a List of model like `List<Model>? modelName;` as a json file in `Hive` local storage?

Here's my `FavoriteRecipeModel`

```
class FavoriteRecipeModel {
  RecipeModel? recipe;
  FavoriteRecipeModel({this.recipe});
  factory FavoriteRecipeModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      FavoriteRecipeModel(
        recipe: json["recipe"] == null ? null : json["recipe"],
      );
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "recipe": recipe == null ? null : recipe,
      };
}
```

As you can see I'm using another model called RecipeModel.
RecipeModel will load a json file which is something like this:

```
            {
                "recipeId": "1",
                "recipeName": "Burger",
                "recipeThumbnailLink":"#",
                "recipeVideoLink": "#",
                "recipeAuthor": "John Doe",
                "category":"Fast Food",
                "time": "15 min",
                "ingredients": [
                    {
                        "id": "ingredient1",
                        "name": "Tomato",
                        "amount": "2 slices",
                        "ingredientThumbnailLink": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "ingredient2",
                        "name": "Onion",
                        "amount": "$ slices",
                        "ingredientThumbnailLink": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "ingredient3",
                        "name": "Spinach",
                        "amount": "2 pieces",
                        "ingredientThumbnailLink": ""
                    }
                ],
                "recipeSteps": [
                    {
                        "id": "step1",
                        "name": "Tomato",
                        "stepThumbnailLink": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "step2",
                        "name": "Onion",
                        "stepThumbnailLink": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "step3",
                        "name": "Spinach",
                        "stepThumbnailLink": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
```

So, considering this two factors, is is possible to save entire recipe as a `List<RecipeModel>?`

I need to write a function that'll save the above mentioned json data. A user can have multiple favorite recipe. If it's possible to save the above mentioned data as `json` format in accordance to the model?

My entire RecipeModel can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/QbY3xiKY).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Serialization/Deserialization

It's very much possible to store the model as a json. You'll have to implement `serialization/deserialization` for conversion between `RecipeModel` and `json map`. I'd recommend using the [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) package to take care of this for you.

### Hive

Another way is, if you want to store the data exactly as a `List<RecipeModel>` then you can do so using [Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) but you'll have to implement a custom `TypeAdaptor` for your model.

It isn't hard at all and this [tutorial](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=R1GSrrItqUs) by **Reso Coder** is a good start.